# Guard doesn't execute passport startegy in nestJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, passport.js, nestjs

I am using nestjs and having an issue with using guards to authenticate a request.

[Gist (full code)](https://gist.github.com/abhyuditjain/e1f0bb9c0a54b1d4aca0410e04b8e247)

```
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException, HttpStatus, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-localapikey-update';
import { size } from 'lodash';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class ApiKeyStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'localapikey') {
    constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
        super();
    }

    async validate(token: string) {
        Logger.log('HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!', 'ApiKeyStrategy');  // Not printed
        const data = await this.authService.authenticateClient(token);
        if (!size(data)) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException('Unauthorized');
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

The `@UseGuards(AuthGuard('localapikey'))` doesn't execute and throws 401 error.

None of the logs are printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the validation function in the `super` constructor of the passport strategy.

```
constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
  super((token, done) => done(null, this.validate(token)));
}
```

---

You can also pass the options object as the first parameter:

```
constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
  super({apiKeyField: 'myapikeyfield'}, (token, done) => done(null, this.validate(token)));
}
```

---

btw: I'd recommend using an instance of `Logger` instead of accessing it statically, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52907695/4694994).

Comment: I noticed that it was working fine when i passed the api key in header under the key 'apiKey'. The localapikey strategy allows to change that by doing "const strat = new LocalApiKeySStrategy(options)". How can I do that here, since PassportStrategy expects the object and not an instance.

Comment: I've added the answer to your additional question as an edit.

Comment: I looked through the code of nest.js and the passport-localapikey-update library. I don't think there are docs. :-|