# How to mock NestJS built-in Logger in Jest

Tags: nestjs, ts-jest

I have a controller that uses NestJS built-in Logger via dependency injection in constructor of the controller:

```
  constructor(private readonly logger: Logger)
```

I want to be able to mock it in my Jest tests to see which methods and with what arguments are being called during logging. I tried this syntax:

```
providers[{
    provide: Logger,
    useValue: {
      log: jest.fn(),
    }
}]
```

In that case this line:

```
    expect(Logger).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Returns:
*Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function*

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your test, you should get the logger back out of the DI context using `moduleFixture.get(Logger)` (or something very similar) and then check `expect(logger.log).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`. `Logger` itself is a class, not a spy or mock, so Jest doesn't know what to do with that.

**Full solution that worked:**

```
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
let logger: Logger;

beforeEach(async () => {
  const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
    providers: [  
      {
        provide: Logger,
        useValue: {
          log: jest.fn(),
        },
      },
    ],
  }).compile();
  logger = moduleRef.get<Logger>(Logger);
});
```

And then later in the test itself:

```
expect(logger.log).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(logger.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Your log message here')
```

Comment: Indeed, I was trying so many options that got confused in them. 

What worked is:
logger = moduleRef.get<Logger>(Logger);

And then: expect(logger.log).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work for whatever reason, so I ended up creating a new logger class that extends `ConsoleLogger` and dependency injected it in since that was a standard for testing anyways. It ended up working nicely because I could put Sentry in that extended class abstracted out of other locations which made testing easier down the road .

Comment: It's frustrating that their documentation is lacking around how to use the built-in logger. I end up back here a few months later looking again  I'm not sure why their logger doesn't seem to follow their own dependency injection model which would make this like testing anything else in the NestJS DI ecosystem.

Comment: @CTS_AE most likely it depends on how the logger is used. I use a custom logger I wrote called [ogma](https://ogma.jaymcdoniel.dev) most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to leave this as an answer for how I've been handling this lately. So next time I'm Googling and end up here I'll remember

### ❌ `jest.mock` Without Success

I've tried using `jest.mock` like I normally would on imports for the `Logger` class from `@nest/common`, but it seems to cause its own problems. Even if you try to keep the original implementation like so:

```js
jest.mock('@nestjs/common', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@nestjs/common'),
  Logger: jest.fn(),
}))
```

I still want to believe there has to be a way to accomplish it like this, but maybe Nest JS's dependency system circumvents Jest's hoisted mocking?

### ✅ Using a Custom Logger with Nest JS's Dependency Injection

This feels like unnecessary lifting, but it follows Nest JS's dependency injection, and allows for extending or overwriting later. If you're already writing tests for Nest JS you're likely familiar with it already.

#### `custom.logger.ts`

```js
import { ConsoleLogger } from '@nestjs/common'

export class CustomLogger extends ConsoleLogger {}
```

#### `some-consumer.spec.ts`

This approach uses the `jest-mock-extended` library, but you could also do something like `@Jay McDoniel`'s answer as well.

```js
import { SomeConsumer } from './some-consumer'
import { CustomLogger } from './custom.logger'
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing'
import { mockDeep } from 'jest-mock-extended'

describe('SomeConsumer', () => {
  let someConsumer: SomeConsumer
  const logger = mockDeep<CustomLogger>()

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        SomeConsumer,
        {
          provide: CustomLogger,
          useValue: logger,
        },
      ],
    }).compile()

    someConsumer = module.get(SomeConsumer)
  })

  it('should do something', () => {
    const result = someConsumer.doSomething()

    expect(result).toEqual('something returned')
  })

  it('should log something', () => {
    someConsumer.doSomething()

    expect(logger.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('something')
  })
})
```

#### `some-consumer.ts`

I figured I would provide an example of the logger being consumed.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { CustomLogger } from './custom-logger'

@Injectable()
export class SomeConsumer {
  constructor(private readonly logger: CustomLogger) {}

  public doSomething(): string {
    this.logger.log('something')

    return 'something returned'
  }
}
```

### ✅ A Second Try with the imported `Logger` from `@nestjs/common`

I saw [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52907695/349659) someone mentioning you could set the logger in the module, so I gave it a shot and it seems to work as well

#### `some-consumer-imported.ts`

```js
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common'

@Injectable()
export class SomeConsumerImported {
  private logger = new Logger(SomeConsumerImported.name)

  public doSomething(): string {
    this.logger.log('something logged')

    return 'something returned'
  }
}
```

#### `some-consumer-imported.spec.ts`

```js
import { SomeConsumerImported } from './some-consumer-imported'
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common'
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing'
import { mockDeep } from 'jest-mock-extended'

describe('SomeConsumerImported', () => {
  let someConsumerImported: SomeConsumerImported
  const logger = mockDeep<Logger>()

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [SomeConsumerImported],
    }).compile()

    module.useLogger(logger)

    someConsumerImported = module.get(SomeConsumerImported)
  })

  it('should do something', () => {
    const result = someConsumerImported.doSomething()

    expect(result).toEqual('something returned')
  })

  it('should log something', () => {
    someConsumerImported.doSomething()

    expect(logger.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('something logged', SomeConsumerImported.name)
  })
})
```

Comment: The last option here is promising, however since `logger` is defined once, whenever I use `expect(logger.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)` within a test, it fails because it is called multiple times due to other tests also triggering it.

Comment: @ChrisBarr Look into having jest reset your mocks between tests via the configuration https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#resetmocks-boolean, or explicitly call `.mockReset()` on your mock. We have it reset mocks between all tests for our default since that is not normal functionality for whatever reason. I guess it depends how how you like to write your tests.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that. I'm used to testing with Jasmine, so Jest's oddities are a little new to me.

Answer (score 0):

A problem is that you *should* inject the logger, but doing it that way you lose the ability to set the context of the current class name, or set options.  So here's what I did to get around this.

I created a new injectable class at `src/app-logger.ts` that allows me to optionally set the context

```ts
import { Injectable, Logger, LoggerService } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppLogger implements LoggerService {
  private readonly options = { timestamp: true };
  private context?: string;

  constructor(private readonly logger: Logger) {}

  setContext(contextName: string): void {
    this.context = contextName;
  }

  error(message: unknown): void {
    this.logger.error(message, this.context, this.options);
  }

  warn(message: unknown): void {
    this.logger.warn(message, this.context, this.options);
  }

  log(message: unknown): void {
    this.logger.log(message, this.context, this.options);
  }

  debug(message: unknown): void {
    this.logger.debug(message, this.context, this.options);
  }

  verbose(message: unknown): void {
    this.logger.verbose(message, this.context, this.options);
  }
}
```

Then in whatever class I want to use it, I inject it and call `setContext()` in the constructor, and then I can use it like the regular logger anywhere in that class.

```ts
@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  constructor(
    private readonly logger: AppLogger,
  ) {
    logger.setContext(TestService.name);
  }
  
  doStuff(): void {
    this.logger.log('hello!');
  }
}
```

So now when I go to write tests I have this `mockAppLogger` which I store in `src/test-helpers.ts` along with other reusable testing methods

```ts
export const mockAppLogger: Record<keyof AppLogger, typeof jest.fn> = {
  setContext: jest.fn(),
  error: jest.fn(),
  log: jest.fn(),
  warn: jest.fn(),
  debug: jest.fn(),
  verbose: jest.fn(),
};
```

So now in my actual test I can just provide that as I would any other injected service

```ts
describe('TestService', () => {
  let service: TestService;
  let logger: AppLogger;
  let repo: Repository<TestEntity>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        TestService,
        { provide: AppLogger, useValue: mockAppLogger }, //<-- provide the mock logger here
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get(TestService);
    logger = module.get<AppLogger>(AppLogger);
  });
  
  it('should log a value', () => {
    jest.spyOn(logger, 'log');
    service.doStuff();
    
    expect(logger.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hello!');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this for private loggers in unit tests:

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

const loggerSpyLog = jest.spyOn(Logger.prototype, 'log');
const loggerSpyWarn = jest.spyOn(Logger.prototype, 'warn');

expect(loggerSpyLog).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
expect(loggerSpyWarn).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

You can just use `jest.SpyOn` on the `Logger` class directly

```
 jest.spyOn(Logger, 'log');

 expect(Logger.Log).toHaveBeenCalledTimes('error', 'SmsService.sendSMS');
```